# How to insert manual activity in Tibco BW work flow process

Tags: tibco

I'm designing a simple business process using Tibco Designer. Basically, it's like

Receive xml data via JMS --> Extract certain data from xml and modify it --> send back the modified xml

So my question is, which activity from Palettes should I choose to implement the manual task ?

For example:

```
original.xml
<xml>
<sender>Jason</sender>
<message>I am hungry</message>
</xml>

modified.xml
<xml>
<sender>Jason</sender>
<message>I am hungry</message>
<modifiedMessage>I am so hungry!!!!!<modifiedMessage>
</xml>
```

So I want to extract  from original.xml and maybe show it on screen, and then ask for user's input for modified message. After user put in message, we will add it as another element and send the modified.xml to other destination.

Answer (score 1):

Well, TIBCO BusinessWorks (as well as TIBCO Designer which is just a modeler for business processes) is not made for that kind of using - human interaction between process steps (activities). You probably need some kind of BPM tool with rich GUI forms and all other fancy stuffs.

With TIBCO BW you can receive JMS message using "JMS Queue Receiver" but you have to know XML schema for that JMS message. After that, you can 'extract' some data from it with for e.g. "Mapper" activity and after that you can send message back to the same queue with "Reply to JMS Message" activity.